# Using generate_series in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to make a column that contains 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 4 4 4 5 5 5 ... all the way to 500 500 500. I was told to try to use generate_series, but haven't been able to figure out a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming Postgres because of `generate_series()`

```
select i
from generate_series(1,500) as t(i)
  cross join generate_series(1,3)
order by i;
```

The first call to `generate_series()` generates the numbers from 1 to 500 and the cross join then triples each row.